# Why can't I create site collections in some CDBs?

Tags: site-collection, content-database

I currently have my SharePoint 2010 server set up with twelve content databases.  In each is or should be one site collection at the moment, but as I went through to set up each one five of them gave me the following error:

> **Error**
>
> The URL 'Reporting Templates/audit.xlsx' is invalid.  It may refer to
>   a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that
>   is not in the current Web.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 20185930-c5b1-4abc-84b5-e5709e1d2241
>
> Date and Time: 11/22/2011 11:02:40 AM

I've checked in **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Reporting\Templates** and confirmed that Audit.xlsx does exist.

Here's my method that I've been using to set up these site collections in these CDBs:

1. Stop all content databases.
2. Start only the content database I want to create a site collection in.
3. Using Central Administration go to Application Management -> Create Site Collections.
4. Enter the appropriate information.  (I'm using the managed path [with Wildcard inclusion] http://servername/departments/ for all of these initial site collections.  The only things that change are the title and the URL of each site collection.)
5. Hit OK.

There seems to be no rhyme or reason as to why those five specific CDBs wouldn't accept a site collection.  While the other seven worked just fine.

Why can't I create site collections in those five CDBs?

**Edit:** I've tried creating a directory in ...\FEATURES called "Reporting Templates" and copying the contents of ...\Reporting\Templates into it in an effort to match the directory that the error says it's trying to reach.  When I go to create a site collection I get the exact same error, though.

**Edit 2:** Using the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and the following command I get the exact same error.

`New-SPSite http://***/departments/clientservices -OwnerAlias ***\*** -ContentDatabase
 WSS_Content_Client-Services -SecondaryOwnerAlias ***\*** -Template STS#0 -Name "Client Services"`

**Edit 3 - 1/5/2012:** If I remove RBS from one of the misfit CDBs and try to add a site collection using the command from Edit 2 it installs correctly!  We've narrowed it down to an RBS issue, ladies and gentlemen!  Additionally after creating that site collection and then reinstalling RBS trying to create another site collection returns the original error.

RBS breaks things.  Great.

Comment: If you take a look at the SQL permissions between a database where this works, and a database where it does not work, is there a difference in which accounts have access and what their rights are?

Comment: @shufler - Nope, they're identical to the ones that work.

Comment: Is this an out of the box site definition you're creating the site collection with or is it custom? Is this the same as the sites that work? You could try searching the 14\TEMPLATES (sub)folders for audit.xlsx to see which template it is using if not sure or to confirm.

Comment: @shufler - OOB.  All are using the same template.

Comment: SharePoint build number? (Central Admin -> System Settings -> Manage Servers in the Farm -> Configuration database version)

Comment: @shufler - 14.0.4762.1000

Comment: Looks like RTM. It may not solve your problem, but you could try installing (at a minimum) SP1.

Comment: @shufler - lol RTM looks like it's missing a F to me.  What is RTM?

Comment: Release To Manufacturing. It's the first version released to the public. In SharePoint 2010's case, you have the version released in April 2010. Since then there has been a cumulative update released every two months. SP1 was released in June and there have since been two more CUs. See  here for updating SharePoint: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847

Comment: @shufler - Okay, I just installed SP1 and my Config DB version is still 14.0.4762.1000...

Comment: Have you run the configuration wizard?

Comment: @shufler - Only that first time after the initial install on the VM.

Comment: @shufler - Hey look at that!  14.0.6029.1000!  No help on this particular issue, however.  Still get the same error as before.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to get a bit more information about the events that lead up to the error by checking the log files in

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

ULS Viewer is a utility that can be used to view, sort, filter etc the log entries based on, for example the correlation id that you are given by the erorr page.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Comment: +1 for good troubleshooting step

Comment: I've taken a look at the appropriate log entries and unless I'm missing something they aren't telling me anything that the error page told me.  What am I looking for?

Comment: @JonnyP - Sorry, they aren't telling me anything that the error page _hasn't_ told me already.

Comment: What happens if you just create new content databases for the sites that aren't working? Would you eventually end up creating all your site collections? If so then just delete all the old non-working dbs when you are done.

Comment: @PaulLucas - I was kind of trying to avoid that, because I'm not 100% sure how to remove the RBS I've installed on each of my current CDBs.

Comment: @PaulLucas - Okay, I just did the following process to one of the offending CDBs with no change to the error I get after it all: **1:** Disabled and removed RBS from the CDB. **2:** Deleted the CDB.  **3:** Created a new CDB (with a slightly different name). **4:** Enabled RBS on the new CDB.  **5:** Attempted to create a new site collection in the new CDB.  ***No dice.***

Comment: Have you tried Mike Oryszak's suggestion of using powershell to create the site?

Comment: @PaulLucas - Edited my question to include results from that.

Answer (score 2):

I may have an answer for you. If my answer is correct, please answer the couple of questions at the end just for my reference.

Check your configuration database for GUIDs with null values. We had the same error and discovered a GUID with null values. Once you have that GUID, you can execute this script to delete the reference to the GUID with null values from your configuration database.

Please be aware that this will modify your configuration database, so you should take every step to back it up and ensure that you have a valid restore point prior to executing this:

```
$wa = get-spwebapplication | ? {$_.displayname -eq "YOURWEBAPPLICATION"}
$wa.contentdatabases.delete('INSERTYOURGUIDHERE')
```

If this works, could you let me know:

1. What was the GUID for your null value content DB?
2. What patch level are you running?

We saw the exact same error, but site collection creation failing maybe 20% of the time. As it ends up, we have many content databases per web app, so it was only failing periodically because of the 1 content database that didn't exist.

Hope this helps!

Edit: I don't find any "official" sources on this. We developed this solution with Microsoft's support. If you wish, you can contact them directly to verify the solution. I'm wondering if this is a SP1 or August CU issue, however, so it may be rare, new or not previously known.

Posting the SQL command here for clarity:

```
select * from dbo.Objects (nolock) 
WHERE Properties LIKE '%<fld type="null" />%'
and Name = 'OFFENDINGWEBAPP'
```

Comment: Can you be a _lot_ more specific with what you're talking about?  Where exactly am I looking for GUIDs?  By "configuration database" I assume you mean SharePoint_Config in MS SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Maybe he is talking about the SiteMap table in the config database?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you are saying that there could be are content databases that are in a state between online and not attached to the farm. They are referenced somewhere in some database but are missing a GUID, or the GUID in the database is not present? The scenario sounds interesting, but I'm not clear where these values should (or should not?) exist.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. No e-mail notifications on replies? :(

Comment: Yes, sharepoint_config is the appropriate database, and I believe that the sitemap table does act as an index for the content databases in the farm.

What you could do is run a select statement on that table, grab the GUIDS, then cross-reference those with the content databases in CA, or export a list of content databases via Powershell. The offending reference should be evident when you look at the entries in the sitemap table.

Comment: Shufler, 

The config database appears to reference a content database that does not exist. The site provisioning job uses the list of content databases from the config database during site creation, and attempts to create a site in the non-existent database, which results in the failure message.

Comment: @MarkGoshorn - Okay, **1:** I rename all my CDBs to not include the GUID in the name for readability's sake, and **2:** dbo.SiteMap is a list of site collections, not CDBs.  What am I still missing?

Comment: @JonnyP Hi JonnyP, to be specific, I suppose that it's not a GUID, but it is a Unique Identifier. Though you eliminate the GUID when you rename the content database, it still includes a unique identification number in the config database. Sorry that I had the wrong table. Our DBAs worked on the SQL side of things. The Objects table actually includes the information that we are looking for. The statement I added to the original answer should return all items for which there is a null property value

Comment: @MarkGoshorn - I've used your query from above but I took out the Name part from the WHERE clause.  It brings up 21 rows, and the Name column for them all starts with `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:workflow{...}` followed by more stuff in place of the {...}.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where I am creating new site collections and I need them to be in a specific content databases I typically script it with PowerShell.  The New-SPSite command will create a site collection, and gives you an option to identify the content database that it uses.

That doesn't appear to be the error though.  Looking at your error, it looks to me that you are not using a standard SharePoint site definition/template.  Is this something you previously exported, and if so are all of the dependencies installed?  Looks like there is a feature or something referencing an excel file.

Comment: The template I'm using is the OOB Team Site template.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [check this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/b833fc4b-695f-448e-986c-da8a8c42d5ae/) where a solution was implemented for a similar problem?

The issue was said to be resolved by recreating the existing SharePoint farm. Though I don't have a clear idea how this is accomplished, I would advice to take all kinds of backup possible, before trying this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to simply disable RBS, then create the site collection, then re-enable RBS (after this, I could create new site collections normally):

```
$cdb=Get-SPContentDatabase <ContentDbName>
$rbs=$cdb.RemoteBlobStorageSettings
$rbs.Disable()
```